# Three20 & TabBarController

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm stuck on something.

I'm using three20 and the TTTNavigator example. Where I can find a TabBarController that is using :

```
[self setTabURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tt://crush",
                                               @"tt://crushes",
                                               nil]];
```

to create each tab.

Ok until here all is ok, my problem is that I have all my tabs without title and image. I know how to set individual when it loads the view controller inside `- (void)viewDidLoad` :

```
    self.title = @"crush";
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.title];
    self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title image:image tag:0] autorelease];
```

but this is a problem because when you init the app all the tabs except the selected are empty.

Any suggest on how to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've resolved, I used the -init method of each view controller.. like usually... but what I need to change was :

```
[self setTabURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tt://crush/1",
                                               @"tt://crushes/2",
                                               nil]];
```

And in the map :

```
[map from:@"tt://crush/(init)" toViewController:[MakeCrushViewController class]];
[map from:@"tt://crushes/(init)" toViewController:[MyCrushesViewController class]];
```

for me right now it looks pretty weird.. but ok is working, don't ask me why you need to set 1 and 2 before the links.. if I set 1 on each it crashes...

Comment: you have to add the number 1 or 2 at the end of the url because in you delegate you have a map to @"tt://crush/(init)". if you change that map to @"tt://crush/" it should work without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This guy had an answer to this question in this blog post.[1](http://www.jefflinwood.com/2010/11/quick-tip-adding-icons-to-three20-tab-bar/)

Basically, within your tab view controller, just access the your view controllers
like you would without three20. In your tab view controller implimentation file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *tabs =  [self viewControllers];

UIViewController *home = [tabs objectAtIndex:0];

home.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redo.png"];

UIViewController *activities = [tabs objectAtIndex:1];
activities.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"restart.png"];
UIViewController *map = [tabs objectAtIndex:2];
map.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lock.png"];
}
```

Comment: yes, but it is better if you try to do it on an init method. Then all the icons on the tabBar are loaded on init not when viewDidLoad are called